# Autoloader issue with Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm new to Zend and am currently trying to use Swift Mailer as my messaging system. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Adviser\Controller\Swift_Message' not found
```

I did some research and thought it might be an autoloader issue. So I added the following two lines:

```
$autoloader = new StandardAutoloader();
$autoloader->registerNamespace('Swift_','/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/zsa/Swift-4.3.0/lib/classes/Swift');
```

I'm still getting the error. I've also set the path accordingly to "swift_required.php"

require_once '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/zsa/Swift-4.3.0/lib/swift_required.php';

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you verified that Swift is sitting inside a namespace?

Comment: @DarylGill Swift actually wasn't namespaced. I realized that after flov posted. I tried checking if other classes like Zend_Mail would also throw the error. Turns out that they also do.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Swift is not namespaced, so you should use $autoloader->registerPrefix instead if available.

Using http://getcomposer.org/ is a good option too.

Comment: Just tried changing registerNamespace to registerPrefix. It's still throwing the same error.

Comment: Can you try ? $autoloader->registerPrefix('Swift','/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/zsa/Swift-4.3.0/lib/classes/');

Comment: According to this post http://blog.lysender.com/2009/10/swiftmailer-on-zend-framework/, it looks like requiring swift_required.php will bootstrap it.

Comment: I tried implementing the Zend_Mail class and got the same error. Seems like Zend just isn't able to find any of the necessary classes?